# Trying to figure out the correct Rails routing for a controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 6
```

I am having an issue, figuring out the correct routing, for a contoller action.

In my controllers/customers_controller.rb, I have the following:

```
def extended_edit
  customer = params[:customer]
  ....
end
```

And in my view, I have a link:

```
td = link_to extended_edit_customer_path(id: 2, customer: customer)
```

In my config/routes.rb, I tried doing:

```
resources :customers do
  member do
    post :extended_edit
  end
end
```

But a GET instead of a POST is generated:

```
 Started GET "/customers/2/extended_edit?...
```

And I get the following error message:

```
No route matches [GET] "/customers/2/extended_edit"
```

My routes:

```
extended_edit_customer POST /customers/:id/extended_edit(.:format)  customers#extended_edit
customers GET    /customers(.:format) customers#index
POST   /customers(.:format) customers#create
new_customer GET    /customers/new(.:format)  customers#new
edit_customer GET    /customers/:id/edit(.:format) customers#edit
customer GET    /customers/:id(.:format)  customers#show
PATCH  /customers/:id(.:format)  customers#update
PUT    /customers/:id(.:format) customers#update
DELETE /customers/:id(.:format) customers#destroy
```

I tried doing:

```
resources :customers do
  collection do
    post :extended_edit
  end
end
```

and changed the link to:

```
td = link_to extended_edit_customers_path(id: 2, customer: customer)
```

To match the new route:

```
extended_edit_customers POST /customers/:id/extended_edit(.:format)  customers#extended_edit
```

But, that takes me to:

```
Processing by CustomersController#show as HTML
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: See my edits. I had a typo in the initial question, as I was copying stuff from another attempt

Comment: Is that link generating a `POST` or a `GET`, what do you see when you inspect it, or in the logs when you hit it, does it show a `POST` getting called or, as I suspect, does it use `GET`?

Comment: No, it's generating a: Started GET "/customers/2/extended_edit?... and the error: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/customers/2/extended_edit")

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct link_to:

`td = link_to extended_edit_customer_path(id: 2, customer: customer), method: :post`

Comment: I already tried that. There's another issue here, probably in my view

Comment: what is the issue or the error when adding method: :post?

Answer (score 0):

You do realize that links by design always send GET requests? That's how web browsers work.

To send a POST request you need to submit a form. In Rails you can use `button_to` to create a discrete form with just a submit button:

```
td = button_to extended_edit_customer_path(customer)
```

This works even if JavaScript is disabled in the browser since its an actual form.

You can also use Rails UJS:

```
td = link_to extended_edit_customer_path(customer, method: :post)
```

This adds a `data-method="POST"` attribute to the link which the Rails UJS driver handles by creating a form object with JavaScript and posting it to the server instead of the normal behavior of sending a GET request. If it does not work and sends a GET request then you most likely have a script error or Rails UJS is missing from your pack.

The routes should be something like:

```
resources :customers do
  member do
    post :extended_edit
  end
end
```

You're also using the wrong param key:

```
def extended_edit
  customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  ....
end
```

Comment: I don't really get what your doing here though and POST might be the wrong http method. A post request should create a new resource.

Comment: I already tried method: :post, and it did not work. I meant to say customer = params[:customer], as I am not looking for the @customer ActiveRecord object, that's another hash I am passing through the link and it's called customer. The issue was with the view rendered by the controller action.

Comment: " that's another hash I am passing through the link and it's called customer" that sounds like a grade A Bad Idea.

Comment: Why would that be a bad idea? You pass things like a collection of check_box selections, as an array

Comment: Because its most likely an overcomplicated solution to a very simple problem that can be done simplely and RESTfuly with nested routes.

Comment: The simple problem, consists of building a wrapper for a Microsoft SQL database, extracting data, and then using that data, in a MySQL Rails application. As elegant as I try to be, at one point, I am faced with having to send an array of hashes (check_box selections), through the form, and up to the controller action